# Can I simplify this PHP expression?

Tags: php, replace

I have the following PHP Function that I want to simplify, What is the best and most efficient way?

```
  function XMLToObject($dirtyXML) {
        $clean_xml = str_ireplace([
            'SOAP-ENV:',
            'SOAP:'
                ], '', $dirtyXML);

      $clean_xml2 = str_ireplace([
            'common:',
            ''
                ], '', $clean_xml);

      $clean_xml3 = str_ireplace([
            'pdt:',
            ''
                ], '', $clean_xml2);
        $clean_xml4 = str_ireplace([
            'apd:',
            ''
                ], '', $clean_xml3);

        $clean_xml5 = str_ireplace([
            'bs7666:',
            ''
                ], '', $clean_xml4);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml5);

        return $xml;
    }
```

I was thinking of using another function like...

```
function replace($oldVal,$newVal)
```

Then iterate over this 4 times with my different value pairs?

Comment: Merge all replaced values in one array

Comment: So  like this? - str_ireplace([
            'pdt:',
            ''
            'SOAP-ENV:',
            'SOAP:'
                ]

Comment: Exactly - `str_ireplace(array(.....), '', $var)`

Comment: Read the documentation on function [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join all occurences to replace into one array:

```
function XMLToObject($in) {
    $find = array('SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP', 'common:', 'pdt:', 'apd:', 'bs7666:');
    $replace = '';
    return simplexml_load_string(str_ireplace($find, $replace, $in));
}
```

Also, there is little value in replacing the empty string with empty string...